# Swift Allocate Array of Pointers

Tags: arrays, swift, pointers, memory

How can I use `UnsafeMutablePointer<T?>` as `UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeRawPointer?>!`

e.g. Trying to allocate n blocks of memory for type T, to get values from a `CFSet cfsetref`:

```
var array = UnsafeMutableRawPointer<T?>.allocate(capacity: n)
CFSetGetValues(cfsetref, array) // error
```

Which gives the error

> Cannot convert value of type '`UnsafeMutablePointer<T?>`' to expected
>   argument type '`UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeRawPointer?>!`'

I tried declaring `array` as `UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeRawPointer?>` then doing

```
for i in 0..<n {
  var d = array[i]
  d?.bindMemory(to: T.self, capacity: 1)
}
```

But I still get `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION` errors when attempting to access `array[i]` (after binding the memory again to `T`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many things depends on how you get your `cfsetref` and what actually is `T`.

But anyway, `CFSetGetValues` expects `UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeRawPointer?>!` as shown in the error message.

```
let n = CFSetGetCount(cfsetref)
let array = UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeRawPointer?>.allocate(capacity: n)
array.initialize(to: nil, count: n)
CFSetGetValues(cfsetref, array)
```

To safely access the contents of `array`, you need to know how `T` is managed by Swift ARC. For example, assuming `T` is `NSNumber`, you need to tell Swift ARC to manage the result with writing something like this:

```
let managedArray = UnsafeMutableBufferPointer(start: array, count: n).map{Unmanaged<NSNumber>.fromOpaque($0!).takeRetainedValue()}
print(managedArray)
```

---

But as well as other CF-collection types, the better way to handle `CFSet` is bridging it to Swift `Set`:

```
if let swiftSet = cfsetref as? Set<NSNumber> {
    let swiftArray = Array(swiftSet)
    print(swiftArray)
}
```

---

How do you get your `cfsetref` and what actually is `T`? With such information, I would try to tell you what sort of code you need to write in your actual case.

Comment: Bridging to `Set` feels right. My `CFSet` is coming from `IOHIDManagerCopyDevices`, where `T` is a `IOHIDDevice`. I was getting nowhere trying to manage my own pointers/memory, but bridging to `Set` seems to work out of the box (and is so much simpler). Thanks so much.